# readhtmltable R does not read

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to use readHTMLTable in R, and it works fine for one webpage, but for another, it does not read in the table.

```
library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(RCurl)
library('SDMTools')
```

this one works, and I access `t[[2]]` for further analysis:

```
url='http://www.nhl.com/ice/schedulebyseason.htm?navid=nav-sch-sea#'
t=readHTMLTable(url)
```

this one does not:

```
url='http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?reportType=season&report=teamsummary&season=20152016&gameType=2&aggregate=0'
t=readHTMLTable(url)
```

How can I access the table from the second one?

Comment: http://www.nhl.com/ice/tos.htm,  2¶: **"Prohibited Content and Activities"** … •  _"Engage in unauthorized spidering, scraping, or harvesting of content or information, or use any other unauthorized automated means to compile information;_"

Comment: The TOS is certainly a important issue but I think the simple programming issue is that the page pops up a message and expects you to click through it.

Comment: both comments make sense. I did not think of reviewing the TOS, but now it makes sense.